# Where does the factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ come from for the fourier transform, from a linear algebra viewpoint?

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-transform

If you have a dot product in 'function space'

$$\langle f,g\rangle$$

This translates to the integral for functions

$$ \langle f,g\rangle =\int f \bar{g} dx $$
If I am not mistaken.

If we have for $g(x)$

$$g(x)=e^{ikx}$$

Then we get
$$ \langle f,g\rangle =\int f \cdot e^{-ikx} dx $$

This looks similar to the fourier transform:

$$ f(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int f(x)\cdot e^{-ikx} dx $$

I think this makes sense because we are calculating how much the function $f(x)$ is pointing in the direction of the base vector (or function) $e_k = e^{ikx}$

I don't understand two things:

1. why do you have to take the complex conjugation of $g$?
2. Also where does the factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ come from? I suspect it comes from normalizing the base vector, but I don't know clearly.

Could someone help me show how both of these can be understood intuitively?

Comment: Are you looking at the Fourier transform or Fourier series? You do not provide integration limits to make it clear. In either case, the normalization factor supplies the preservation of the $L^2$ norm. In the Fourier transform case, that tells us that the Fourier transform is a unitary operator (or rather extends to one). In the Fourier series case, it tells us that the $L^2$ information of our function is entirely encoded in its Fourier coefficients.

Comment: $2 \pi$ or not $2 \pi$, that is the question ?

Answer (score 8):

All inner products want to satisfy the identity $\langle f,f\rangle \ge 0$, which is why we take the complex conjugate. When $f$ is potentially complex, there is no reason why $f^2$ (or its integral) should be nonnegative. On the other hand, $f \bar f$ simplifies to $|f|^2$, which is guaranteed to be nonnegative, and when we integrate it, we get a nonnegative value.

The reason for the factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ is that the function $g_k$ we should be looking at is $g_k(x) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{ikx}$. (I've added a subscript to $g$ to remind us that there's many such functions.) The reason we look at this function $g_k$ is that it satisfies $$\langle g_k,g_k\rangle = \int_0^{2\pi} g_k(x) \overline {g_k(x)}\,dx = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{ikx}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \cdot \frac{e^{-ikx}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \,dx = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac1{2\pi}\,dx = 1.$$ Together with the fact that $\langle g_k, g_l\rangle = 0$ when $k \ne l$, this makes the sequence $g_0, g_1, g_2, \dots$ an orthonormal basis of a vector space.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very clear answer of my questions!! I have one more question, why do we choose to integrate on the interval $[0,2\pi]$?

Comment: That's the interval on which this inner product makes sense for the $g_k$ functions (even before we pick the constant factor). From a practical point of view, the interval needs to be bounded, or else $\langle g_k, g_k\rangle$ does not converge. Also, $g_k$ is periodic with a period of $\frac{2\pi}{k}$, so an interval like $[0,2\pi]$ captures all the information about it in some sense (something like $[-\pi,\pi]$ would work equally well.)